# str' object has no attribute 'load_img'

Tags: image-processing, keras, multilabel-classification, loadimage

I wanted to load all the images from a folder and make predictions on those images

this is what i tried

```
    images = []
    folder_path="C:/Users/Harsh/Desktop/Ornithopter/anv/train/images/"
    for img in os.listdir(folder_path):
     img = image.load_img(img, target_size=(img_width, img_height))
     img = img.img_to_array(img)
     img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
     images.append(img)
```

The above mentioned error arises on the line 
`img = image.load_img(img, target_size=(img_width, img_height))`

Comment: Kindly downvote my question only if you can answer it,because i am genuinely looking for the answer

Answer (score 3):

You have overwritten the `image` variable with a string instead of keeping it to the `keras.preprocessing.image` module. This would happen if you do:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
```

And then set `image` to anything. Be careful with naming variables the same as a package or a module.

Comment: actually  I wanted to have a prediction on the all images inside a paticular directory can you please provide me an alternative way to do that  @Matias Valdenegro

Comment: @HarshRis That seems to be a different question than the one that was asked.

Comment: Actually what you told previously was taken into consideration already what I really needed was to make prediction on all images stored in a directory -@Matias Valdenegro any possible suggestions for my problem if you could give??